# How do I package and deploy a single Azure web app containing several virtual apps from Visual Studio Team Services (previously VS Online)?

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops, webdeploy

I have a Visual Studio solution that contains two web applications (our main site and our WebAPI project).  I am able to host them locally in IIS Express as a single site using the applicationhost.config, but I want to package them (in our Build) and then deploy them (in our Release) as a single site from Visual Studio Online (which hosts our code) to Azure.

My Visual Studio Team Services Build configuration packages each of the Visual Studio projects into its own Web Deploy package.  The Web Deploy packaging is done during my Build phase, and the deployment to Azure is done during the Release phase - this is done so I am not recompiling source every time I do a deployment, which is unnecessary and would slow down the process.

The first web application identifies "HelloAzure" as the DeployIisAppPath in its pubxml file.  The second one (the WebAPI project) identifies "HelloAzure/api" as the DeployIisAppPath in its pubxml file.

Currently, I am using two of the "Azure Web Site Deployment" steps (the one that uses Service Endpoints to perform a deployment).  I name the same web app name for both steps. When the second project is deployed, it seems to overwrite the first one rather than adding a second application to the existing site. I believe I must not be following the intended practice for deploying several Web Deploy packaged applications into one web site from Visual Studio Team Services to Azure, but I can't find the recommended practice documented anywhere.

I do need to have both applications hosted within a single site.  Deploying them as separate sites is not an option.

It appears that Kudu has some options that might support this scenario, but I am not deploying from source code, I am deploying from Web Deploy packages created by our Team Services build.

Answer (score 2):

The MSDeployAllTheThings VSTS extension supports deployment to a virtual app in an Azure site.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rschiefer.MSDeployAllTheThings

Microsoft also seems to have added official support for deploying to virtual apps from VSTS to Azure to the AzureRM VSTS extensions according to this thread:  https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/624